# ASP.NET MVC 5 : Using EditorTemplates as Snippets

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 for a project, and while I like the model binding capabilities of MVC, I do not find myself using them much because I am using javascript MVVM systems, and I find that it is hard to do these with the model binder.

But I do find myself re-using HTML code a lot for specific inputs that need to be replicated across multiple places.

Is there any way to use the `@Html.EditorFor` etc and instead of specifying a property, just call upon a specific template to use it like a small inline snippets engine?

## Update

Hey guys, I went with the suggestion to use Partial Views, but I changed it up a bit. I'd like to post my solution on StackOverflow for feedback, as I want to know if this is a good practice or not, but for now I am accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own user interface.
do the following steps:

go to Views\Shared
and create [EditorTemplates] folder.
then create your own *.cshtml file for each type or UIHint attributes
for example Create Int32.cshtml as follow for int type:

```
@model int?

@{
    int i;
    if (!Model.HasValue)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        i = Model.Value;
    }

    var htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary();
    if (ViewBag.@class != null)
    {
        htmlAttributes.Add("class", "form-control " + ViewBag.@class);
    }
    else
    {
        htmlAttributes.Add("class", "form-control");
    }

    if (ViewBag.placeholder != null)
    {
        htmlAttributes.Add("placeholder", ViewBag.placeholder);
    }
}

<div class="form-group@(Html.ValidationErrorFor(m => m, " has-error"))">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBox(
            "",
            ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
            htmlAttributes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m, null, new { @class = "help-block" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use partial views for that.